# Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Programming'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I'm using a button to add product to database when clicking it. this is the code which I written, but it creates an unhandled exception. please help me to correct it...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = @"~\Images" + FileUpload1.FileName;
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(s));
    string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HoriZon"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection NewCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
    NewCon.Open();

    String cmd1 = "INSERT INTO Subjects(SubjectName, Description, ImagePath, UnitPrice, CategoryID) values('" + name.Text + "','" + description.Text + "','" + s + "', '" + price.Text + "', '" + "SELECT CategoryID FROM dbo.Categories WHERE CategoryName = '" + catText.Text + "'" +"')";
    SqlCommand b = new SqlCommand(cmd1, NewCon);

    b.ExecuteNonQuery();

    NewCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is exception you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a parameterized query instead of string concatenation

```
String cmd1 = @"INSERT INTO Subjects(SubjectName, Description, ImagePath, UnitPrice, CategoryID) 
               values(@name, @desc, @img, @price, (SELECT CategoryID FROM dbo.Categories 
               WHERE CategoryName = @cname))";
SqlCommand b = new SqlCommand(cmd1, NewCon);
b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name.Text );
b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc",description.Text );
b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img",s);
b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price",price.Text );
b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname",catText.Text);
b.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, the subquery that returns the CategoryID should be enclosed in parenthesis (at least testing it directly in SSMS requires the parenthesis)